# Java plug-in not starting in IE11

Tags: windows-7, java, internet-explorer, java-applet

I have upgraded my browser from ie 8 to ie 11 Enterprise Mode.

When I access my site, the Java popup isn't showing and nothing happens. Its like the Java applet isn't loading. In ie8 when I have access the site the Java applet loaded immediately.

I have even include this site in the Enterprise Mode list, and its not working.

I have opened the Add-on menu and the Java is enabled there.
I have digged the internet for options and flags and nothing works.

Its Windows 7 64bit, java 6 update 18 64bit, IE 11 with Enterprise mode.

Thanks

Comment: I assume you have to use Java 6 despite it being extremely vulnerable to exploits and out of date?

Comment: Unfortunately you are right. We can't use anything else...

Comment: Is [ActiveX Control Blocking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn761713.aspx) enabled?